# Angular2 routing wait for obtain params from url

Tags: angular2-routing

I want to:

1. Obtain param from url
2. Then send http request to API with that param

If I done it undirectly via browser url box it works great but when I use `router.navigate(["/users", "userName"]);` it work to slow.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this._route.params.subscribe(
        params => {
            this.userName = params['name'];
    });
    this._usersService.getUser(this.userName)
            .subscribe(user => this.user = user,
                       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

This is code inside UserComponent.

And the `this._userService` is sometimes done before `this.sub` is.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switchMap` in order to switch from `params` observable to the observable provided by `getUser()`.

```
// an observable of users
this.user$ = this._route.params
// switch to the observable provided by getUser() which queries the resource
  .switchMap(params => this.getUser(params['name']))
  // log error
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Error occurred - ' + error.message);
    // rethrow
    return Observable.throw(error);
  })
  // share a single subscription among the subscribers so that getUser() will not be called for every subscriber
  .share();
```

Then you can project this observable into another one that is useful for your case, for example:

```
// an observable of user details to be displayed on template
this.userInfo$ = this.user$.map(user => user.username + ' - ' + user.date.toISOString());
```

And finally you can use the observable in your template:

```
The user is: {{ userInfo$ | async }}
```

See the working sample in this [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/ITTA9kwfTg5KzOHvu2yN?p=preview)

Full code for the `UserComponent`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  template: `The user is: {{ userInfo$ | async }}`
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  public user$: Observable<User>;
  public userInfo$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // an observable of users
    this.user$ = this._route.params
    // switch to the observable provided by getUser() which queries the resource
      .switchMap(params => this.getUser(params['name']))
      // log error
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error occurred - ' + error.message);
        // rethrow
        return Observable.throw(error);
      })
      // share a single subscription among the subscribers so that getUser() will not be called for every subscriber
      .share();

    // an observable of user details to be displayed on template
    this.userInfo$ = this.user$.map(user => user.username + ' - ' + user.date.toISOString());
  }

  private getUser(username: string): Observable<User> {
    // occasionally create error
    if (username === 'error') {
      return Observable.throw(new Error('Occasional error'));
    }

    // create a user after 300 ms
    return Observable.of({username: username, date: new Date()}).delay(300);
  }
}

export interface User {
  username: string;
  date: Date;
}
```